# is there a way to replace a file with another file with the same name without windows asking about it?

Tags: windows, server

I have a folder on a server , which I want whenever a file like "hello.txt" is sent to this folder , if another file "hello.txt" already exists in that folder , the new file be replaced with the old one without any asking!(automatically)

Comment: This is a programming question or are you asking as user?

Comment: I'd rather use an application like a file manager app or something else,

Comment: Then you should ask this in SuperUser community, here is only for programmers/developers.